# Converting string to date time by parsing

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting a string in the following format

```
string dt=  "\"2014-06-01T05:00:00.000Z\""
```

I am trying to convert it to Date following way

```
mDateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dt)
```

I get error saying When converting string to date time use parse the string.
Please let me know how I can parse the string to date. Thanks

Comment: Side note: Are you sure strings you actually need to parse have quotes and it is not JSON or XML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method fails because this is not a standard date and time pattern for your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (And probably no culture support this format).

You can use custom date and time formatting with [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

Here an example on [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "\"2014-06-01T05:00:00.000Z\"";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\"'", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump();
}
```

Output will be;

```
6/1/2014 5:00:00 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/bmeero)</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

At first you have to trim quotes, then parse:

```
DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(dt.Trim('\"'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
string dt = "\"2014-06-01T05:00:00.000Z\"";
dt = dt.Replace("\"", "");
DateTime dtFinal = DateTime.ParseExact(dt,"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ",
                                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use below menioned code

```
string dt = "\"2014-06-01T05:00:00.000Z\"";
dt = dt.Replace("\"", "");
DateTime dt12 = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);
```